# 'Could not load oracle.dataAccess or dependencies'

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to run a winform project, that use OracleDataAccess dll.

I am doing it with the x32 (so compilation x86), so I can add a Setup project.

But I got the errors  `could not load file OracleDAtaAccess or its depedencies` when I run my form.

So I search, and found I must also referer :

```
oci.dll
orannzsbb11.dll
oraociei11.dll
OraOps11w.dll
```

But, I cannot add them as references on my project.

I don't understand.

It all compile in x86, I reference the dll oracle data access in the GAC_32, and I got this error.

Can someone give me some help and explanations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to help as my Oracle is rusty now. Hope this can help.

When you install Oracle client, you know your Oracle HOME and Directory. All Oracle required libraries are installed there. If you dig deeper into those directories (or use search on those folders), you will find your DLLs there. I think you can add references to those DLLs to your project as I did many times before.